# How to configure Gitlab/Docker/AWS?

Tags: docker, gitlab, amazon-ecs

I have a Gitlab project, hosted in my company's Gitlab account. I have written an .gitlab-ci.yaml file which gather the image `image: python:3.10.9-bullseye`, install the python dependencies and run the tests. Now I would create a Docker image and send it to AWS ECR. I'm blocked here.

I don't know how to call/use the Docker CLI and AWS CLI.
Can someone explain me how to?